# Different style for same element

Tags: html, css

I have a site that is generated by an application using a template.
My problem is that I am trying to use some transition effects on some images.

The code for the images and transitions is set in `<ul> & <li>` elements but that messes up the template `<ul> & <li>` styles.
Is there a way for me to set some css that still targets the `<ul> <li>` elements but picking out the one I want set on the image code.

Comment: can you use a class or id on the elements?

Answer (score 1):

you can select li by `:nth-of-type()` and give your special style

```css
li:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
li:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: green;
}
li:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: blue;
}
li:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
  <li>asd</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Not sure if that code will help me as I would have to count the <ul> tags. I was hoping that there was some code that could say something like, if it's this <ul> do this css or if it's this <ul> then do this CSS.

Comment: it will be better if we see the code that you write or some example, also can we use jquery it well be helpful